# Incurred CPU-side conversion error crashes Browser while loading an object in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

When using the exact same code like in the threejs example/loader/obj/mtl example while loading an object exported via Unity3d, we have some browser crashes on customer machines. Here is a screenshot from a browser console:[Browser Screenshot Firefox newest version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGQed.png)

Here you find the statistics shown via threex.rendererstats.js
[threex Renderstats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYDiu.jpg)

Because i do not have the experience using threejs i do not now if the geometries are to big, asking myself if there are any restrictions although the gpu is used. threejs Version is r83.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a texture format that is not supported on some GPUs, so it is being converted on the CPU. See the discussion on this thread for more details:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9109

Comment: You mean texImage2D? Any workaround solutions? As i can find nothing and i am using only standard threejs stuff so i will not change the threejs source.

Comment: Yeah the combination of format, type that are passed to texImage2D are not supported on that GPU.

Comment: Though are you sure that error is actually what's causing the crash? If you temporarily change the texture format to one that doesn't require the conversion (or remove it entirely) does the crash go away?